# Angular2 MDL input box labels visible after data binding

Tags: angular, material-design-lite

I am using material design lite and my input box has following code:

```
<div #textfield class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
    <textarea rows="4" class="my-input mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="user-desc" [ngModel]="short_story" (ngModelChange)="getShortStory($event)"></textarea>
    <label class="my-label mdl-textfield__label" for="user-desc">That's my short story!</label>
</div>
```

When I get data from my server and is bound to the input box, the label is still visible in the background. How to hide/remove it in such cases. If I start typing, it goes away, but initially it does not good at all.

[image]

Comment: Seems you have problem with your styles. Can you create working example?

Comment: I have similar problem :-/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44528717/how-can-i-programmatically-mark-text-field-as-invalid