# How can I programmatically mark text field as invalid?

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-design-lite

How can I programmatically mark text field as invalid in Material Design Light?

My HTML code:

```
  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
    <input id="email" type="email" class="mdl-textfield__input">
    <label for="email" class="mdl-textfield__label">Email</label>
    <span class="mdl-textfield__error">Email is invalid or already taken!!!</span>
  </div>
```

I added *is-invalid* class in JavaScript but it displays badly:

[image]

Comment: Side note: multiple exclamation marks come over as highly aggressive.

Comment: Use AJAX to send requests to a PHP file which deliberately checks the database for emails to see if email is taken. That or have it submit on a button click instead.

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript to make sure the entered email is valid via JavaScript